# Same Meteor project for web app and mobile apps

Tags: angular, meteor, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

I searched a lot and didn't find a lot about using one Meteor project to develop web app and hybrid mobile apps. I would like to be able to share all the logic and only have to set views depending on the platform (web, iOS or Android). I want to use Angular as frontend framework.

Do you think this is something possible with Meteor ?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using Meteor's Cordova integration. Here is the doc: [Meteor with Cordova](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html).

Even if it is not obvious at first, this is meant to share the code between web and mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into `react-native` or `nativescript` as well. They compile to native UI components and there are libraries available to talk DDP with Meteor.